# Bootstrap modal AngularJS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, angularjs

Использую [**angular-ui/bootstrap**](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). И при созданиии модального окна - оно создается каждый раз. Можно создать html мадального окна, и открывать его? Но нужно именно методом данной библиотеки!

Вывожу окно так:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({/*params*/});
```

Comment: можете описать более подробно проблему? конкретно по этой реализации - `$modal.open` возвращает объект с методами `close` и `dismiss` - то есть открыть заново не получится

Comment: нужно не создавать окно каждый раз, а открывать заново

Comment: _то есть открыть заново не получится_. Ну либо я не понимаю, вы что вкладываете в эти понятия :-)

Comment: в чем кстати проблема создавать каждый раз?

Comment: Окно большое, и при создании долго происхрдит рендер. И так постоянно... и я думал так решить проблему

Comment: можете пример окна показать? возможно стоит просто облегчить его?

Comment: пример не  могу показать... там в форме есть 3-5 селектов которые исползуют bootstrap selectpicker

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32356/discussion-between-grundy-and-myvzar).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал использовать `iframe`. Он будет отдельно грузиться, и не будет долго грузить всё окно.